# change jquery selector to not select particular div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery selector that I would like to change so that it wont select `<div id="divA"></div>`.

Heres the current selector:

```
$('ul.toggle a').on('click', function () {
  //does some work
});
```

I tried `$('ul.toggle a [id!=divA]')` but that thows errors.
What is the intended format for this selector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**:not**](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```
$("ul.toggle a:not('#mhs-link')")
```

Comment: I like this method better - don't know why the other one came to mind first :P

Comment: @kev - I don't think either of them are too readable - they just uglify the selectors (IMO). In a case where I find myself needing to exclude only one specific element from a selector, it's usually because I structured something incorrectly....

Comment: this worked, @Lix I agree that i have some structure issues, but I don't have the time to restructure the .js and .css I got from UX right now.  This quick fix did the job.

Comment: @cob - we've all been there :P Glad we could lend a hand!

Answer (score 5):

How about this-

```
$('ul.toggle a').not('#divA')
```

The `.not()` function simply removes elements from a previous list of elements. Because of some nifty function chaining, you can just insert that into your current definition -

```
$('ul.toggle a').not("#divA").on('click', function () {
  //does some work
});
```

References

- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) - Remove elements from the set of matched elements.